# How to fix UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_lines' referenced before assignment

Tags: variables, python-3.x, variable-assignment, local

So this is my function which is meant to read the lines of text from a file.

This is extracted from a larger program hence some of the comments may seem out of place. Anyways I need to use the functions text and file_lines in numerous other functions but even after declaring them as global I still get the UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_lines' referenced before assignment error and I don't know what to do.

```
import sys
text = []
case = ''
file_lines = []
def read_file(file):        # function to read a file and split it into lines
    global text             #sets variable text as a global variable for use in multiple locations
    global case             #handles case sensitivity.
try:                    #tests the statement after colon
    open(file) 
except:
    print('oops no file found bearing that name')      
else:                  
    while file == '':   #if the file name is blank print error, this prevents program from crashing
        print ('error')
        filename = input('enter a file and its extension ie file.ext\n>>')
    with open(file) as f :      #opens filewith name 

        text = f.read() #read all lines of program text.
        print ("file successfully read")
        print('TEXT SENSITIVITY TURNED ON !!!!!!')
        text = text.split('\n')# breaks lines in file into list  instead of using ".readlines"
                               # so that the program doesn't count blank lines 
        case == True

    global file_lines
    file_lines = text
```

a function that tries to use the read_lines variable would be

```
def find_words(words):        
    line_num = 0    # to count the line number
    number_of_word = 0
    if case == False:
        words = words.lower()
        file_lines = [file_lines.lower() for file_lines in text]
    while "" in file_lines:
            file_lines.remove('')      
    for lines in file_lines:

        line_num += 1
        if words in lines:  #checks each for the words being looks for
           print(line_num,"...", text[line_num-1])
           number_of_word = 1
    if number_of_word == 0: #to check if the word is located in the file
        print('Words not found')
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation or we won’t be able to help you. Paste in the code exactly as it is, select it all, and press Ctrl+K to format it as code. Also please include the exact error message including the stack trace, so we know where the error is actually occurring.

Comment: done after much struggling

Comment: A better question would be how to write this without needing a bunch of global variables.

Comment: john if you could help me with that, it would be even more awesome, i just started learning python so right now my aim is just to get it too work. Efficiency isn't really top priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function find_words you forgot to specify that `find_lines` is global. Try

```
def find_words(words):
   global file_lines
   line_num = 0    # to count the line number
```

The function errors because `file_lines` is not defined within the scope of `find_words` otherwise.

Comment: is find_words defined in a separate file as find_lines? If it is, you need to use other_file.find_lines to reference it, after importing other_file

Comment: for unknown reasons it now works.I started over and applied your fix. One bridge finally crossed. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `file_lines`?